# Show that $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in J} A_{\alpha}$ contains $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}$ if $J \subset I$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just wonder if my working is right. Let $(A_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$ be an indexed family of subsets of a set $S$. Let $J \subset I$.     Want to show : $\cap_{\alpha \in J} A_{\alpha} \supset \cap_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}$

Attempts: First of all, if we reduce it to the case of 3 sets we see that the above relation holds (draw Venn diagrams...) Let $x \in \cap_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}$. Then we have $x \in A_{\alpha} \forall \alpha \in I$. Since $J \subset I$, we have $x \in A_{\alpha} \forall \alpha \in J$.

I think my argument is not solid though, even if the relation to be shown just seems kind of trivial.

Comment: Your argument is solid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B=\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in J}A_\alpha$, $C=\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I\setminus J}A_\alpha$ and $D=\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$. The hypothesis is that $J\subseteq I$. This is equivalent to $I=J\cup(I\setminus J)$, which implies that $D=B\cap C$ by definition. Hence $D\subseteq B$.